# React-Native Upgrade 0.26 "Super expression must either be null or a function, not null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

After upgrading from ReactNative 0.25 to 0.26 i get this well known error:

"**Super expression must either be null or a function, not null**".

I know that the most common reason is to import 'Component' from 'react-native' instead from 'react'.

But in all my components i do it right apparently:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Has anyone experienced another root cause for this error? For now, i create a second, complete new project and try to build it up from  scratch with the already existing code of the main project until the error may occur someday. But this is really a time killer....

I don't use RNMK-Library, which is known for this deprecation.

My Dependencies seems to be valid for 0.26:

```
"dependencies": {
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "react": "15.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.26.2",
    "react-native-app-intro": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-button": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-navbar": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.22.23",
    "react-native-router-redux": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-search-bar": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-simple-store": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.8.3",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.4.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^2.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-saga": "^0.10.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "rnpm": "^1.7.0"
}
```

Comment: “Super expression must either be null or a function, not null” How can it be null if it can't be null? Doesn't that just limit it to being a function?

Comment: What line throws the error? Please show us that code.

Comment: @bergi unfortunatly that error doesnt show the correct line of code, only some internals that are wrapped around the really thing. Just look at my own answer to this question. I figured out that a library caused this issue, which are not ready for RN 0.26

Answer (score 0):

In between i found out the root cause and provided a pull request to the following library: https://github.com/Qwikly/react-native-router-redux/pull/46

(but the dependencies of this library should be updated also, i wrote about it in the comments section of the PR)